# Python Twisted proxy - how to intercept packets

Tags: python, http, twisted, packet, intercept

I'm trying to print out the body of a HTTP response using Python.

Here is my code sofar:

```
from twisted.web import proxy, http
from twisted.internet import reactor
from twisted.python import log
import sys

log.startLogging(sys.stdout)

class ProxyFactory(http.HTTPFactory):
  protocol=proxy.Proxy

reactor.listenTCP(8080, ProxyFactory())
reactor.run()
```

When I connect my browser to localhost:8080, I can see that all my requests are being directed through the Python proxy running locally. But how do I 1) print out response body and 2) edit the response body before sending it back to the browser?

I hope someone can point me in the right direction - please bear in mind that I'm very new to Python!

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Override the [dataReceived](http://twistedmatrix.com/documents/current/api/twisted.internet.protocol.Protocol.html#dataReceived) method of a protocol (proxy.Proxy in your case) and handle the data modification in that method:

```
from twisted.web import proxy, http
from twisted.internet import reactor
from twisted.python import log
import sys

log.startLogging(sys.stdout)

class MyProxy(proxy.Proxy):
    def dataReceived(self, data):

      # Modify the data here
      print data

      # perform the default functionality on modified data 
      return proxy.Proxy.dataReceived(self, data)

class ProxyFactory(http.HTTPFactory):
  protocol=MyProxy

factory = ProxyFactory()
reactor.listenTCP(8080, factory)
reactor.run()
```

Comment: Hey, many thanks for that reply. I got an exception - File "proxy4.py", line 15, in dataReceived
     return super(MyProxy,self).dataReceived(data)
 exceptions.TypeError: must be type, not classobj

Comment: Corrected the code. Can you check if it is still raising TypeError?.

Comment: you might mean: `proxy.Proxy.dataReceived(self, data)` instead of `MyProxy.dataReceived(self, data)` othewise it leads to stackoverflow.

Comment: Also `dataReceived()` sees only data send by client to server. Getting the data send by server to client might be [more complicated](http://stackoverflow.com/a/9469400/4279)

Comment: @J.F.Sebastian Tried the code using Chrome and Safari and received an `Unhandled Error`. Are you getting the same problem?

Comment: @Nyxynyx: No. Are you trying to visit the proxy as a web server? You should not put the proxy url into the browser address bar. Configure network settings to use the proxy as a proxy instead. Note: only simple html pages will work if their content is uppercased (`buffer.upper()`)