# twisted - print IP datagrams from/to proxy

Tags: python, twisted

I have a [twisted](http://twistedmatrix.com/trac/) proxy from here: [Python Twisted proxy - how to intercept packets](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9063583/python-twisted-proxy-how-to-intercept-packets) .

It prints the HTTP data, and I would like also to intercept and examine the *raw IP datgrams*. How to hook the callback for the IP packets?

http://twistedmatrix.com/documents/11.0.0/api/twisted.pair.ip.IPProtocol.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Twisted doesn't have a built-in friendly way to hook in a listener on a raw IP socket (SOCK_RAW). This is for several reasons:

- using SOCK_RAW can be tricky and it can work in non-obvious ways;
- in most environments, using such a socket requires elevated privileges;
- and the packets you actually get through a raw socket differ a lot between operating systems (e.g., you won't get any raw TCP-protocol IP packets on *BSD/Darwin through a raw socket, even if you're root).

The best way to capture raw datagrams in general, in a remotely portable manner, is with libpcap. [Here](http://dound.com/2009/09/integrating-twisted-with-a-pcap-based-python-packet-sniffer/) is a link to someone who appears to have combined pcap and Twisted in a reasonably intelligent way; that may help.

Answer (score 1):

Twisted doesn't include comprehensive support for operating at the IP level.  There is some support for parsing IP datagrams, as you found, but no built-in support for hooking into platform support for sending or receiving these.

You might want to take a look at [scapy](http://www.secdev.org/projects/scapy/).